# fiddler HTTPMethod (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE...) Column

Tags: http, fiddler

#### Is there an easy way to add an HTTPMethod (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE...) column to the fiddler display?

Found these instructions on the [fiddler wiki](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/configurecolumns.asp) for adding session variables:

> cols add "Client IP Address" X-CLIENTIP

But HTTPMethod doesn't seem to be as easy.

Anybody know a way to do this or have a good fiddler script?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Edit your rules, then in the class Handlers add:

```
public static BindUIColumn("Method", 60)
    function FillMethodColumn(oS: Session){

        return oS.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod; 
    }
```

Answer (score 209):

There's an easier way now (as of v4.4.5.1 or earlier).

**Right-click** the **column bar** and select **Customize columns...**.

Collection: Miscellaneous
Field Name: RequestMethod
[image: Screenshot of Customize Columns dialog box]

Result:
[image: Screenshot of new created column]

Comment: this is more intuitive

Comment: Don't you mean _"or later"_? Any way, +1.

Comment: No, I did mean _or earlier_. Basically it works on this version, and I'm not sure how many versions ago it was added. haha

Comment: Note that if you add this to a running session, Fiddler won't go back and populate this column for existing transactions (adding a column doesn't cause Fiddler to re-parse data that it already rendered). If you export those sessions to a .saz file and reimport them then Fiddler with re-render that data and populate the new column. I mention this because I added this column in an instance of Fiddler where I had already captured data, and was initially confused upon seeing an empty "Method" column.